# Http headers for starting a multithreaded download

Tags: multithreading, node.js, http-headers, download

I am trying to create a multi threaded downloader using nodejs. Currently I am only able to download the file using a single thread. Its a simple http.get request in nodejs.

To create a multi threaded downloader I will have to send some http headers in my request which I am not able to figure out some how. I want to know what http headers should I be sending so that I am able to download a range of bytes from an offset.

```
var http = require('http');

var options = {
  host: 'hostname.com',
  path: '/path/to/a/large/file.zip',
  headers: {
    //Some headers which will help me download only a part of the file.
  }
};

callback = function(response) {
  response.on('data', function (chunk) {
     //write chunk to a file
  });
}

http.request(options, callback).end();
```

Comment: be more specific, "tell me the headers" - for what exactly?

Comment: i don't believe, there are http headers that will allow you to download a part of a file, but you can start reading the download and manipulate the file once it finishes downloading.

Comment: 14.35 Range under http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html

Comment: 'range': 'bytes=0-10000' this would mostly work

Comment: it does give an example at the same document ..
`Content-Range: bytes 21010-47021/47022`
 -> `Content-Range: bytes START-END/TOTAL`

Comment: its actually the 'Range' header for requests. not the the content-range header as that is for responses only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `Range` header. Example is given in [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#range-request-header)

```
Range: bytes=500-999
```

For more detail see **14.35 Range** in [HTTP header Definitions](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html)